# Referencing Field from 1 class in another

Tags: c#, class, oop

Lets say I have two classes, `Project` and `Document`. `Document` is a class for documents that belong to a certain Project. I am referencing `ProjectID` as its own property in `Document`. Should I be doing this or should I be referencing `Project` in order to get to the project id?
An example of when I am using the Project ID in the document class is when I am adding a new document and need to know the Project that document belongs to.

```
public class Project
{
    private int _ID;
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }
}

public class Document
{
    private int _ID
    private string _Title
    private int _ProjectID

    public int ID
    {
         get { return _ID; }
         set { _ID = value; }
    }
    public string Title
    {
         get { return _Title; }
         set { _Title = value; }
    }
    public int ProjectID
    {
         get { return _ProjectID; }
         set { _ProjectID = value; }
    }
    public DataSet GetDocumentsByProjectID()
    {
        var dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper();
        dbhelper.CommandText = "Get_Documents_By_Project_Select";
        SqlParameter[] parameterList = {
            new SqlParameter("projectid", ProjectID)
        };
        dbhelper.CommandParameters = parameterList;
        return dbhelper.ExecuteQuerySP();
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing you should do is use [auto properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) instead of what you are doing:  `public int ID { get; set; }`  It will reduce your code by a ton

Comment: It really depends on how you will use `Document` in your code. For example, as it stands, it represents a database table (normally called an Entity) perfectly. Can you add some code so we understand the context of these classes?

Comment: I added an example, I think that's where I am having some confusion as well is representing it as an entity or representing it as only properties a document should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes you are showing are normally referred to as entities. These are supposed to represent a database table as much as possible. Taking this into account, the only way to store the reference to a Project from a Document, is through a `ProjectId` property inside the Documents table.
The second part of this way of modelling classes, is to add *navigational properties* that are meant to make it easier to *navigate* (go from parent to children and from child to parent) relationships.

If you used an ORM, like Entity Framework or NHibernate, that is more or less how you would define your classes.

A not-so-minor nitpick, is that you should use auto-properties to define your properties and remove the backing fields.

Your entities should, then, look like this:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why do I use both ProjectID and a reference to the Project Class inside the Document class?

Comment: @Marc Because ProjectId represents what's stored, while the Project property is only an in-memory helper

Comment: Is using the entity framework the best way of doing this? I think with the exception of how my classes are set up im not using a entity framework

Comment: Entity Framework is an ORM. Whether you need it or not depends on the needs of the application, but it's a fast way to develop database-oriented application

Answer (score -1):

A single project may contains multiple documents, in that case relationship will be **Many-to-One** (Many documents for a single project). In Many to one relationship, if we keep Project as a property field, then **project details will be ambiguous**. In that case your approach will be better.

```
public class Document
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Elegant approach**

you can create list of Documents in Project class, this will achieve Many-to-One relationship

```
public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Documents> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide reason for downvote, so I can improve my answer

Answer (score -2):

Add the Project as a property in the Document class and take out projectID

```
    public Project Project { get; set; }
```

Comment: The question is not how to do it, but whether it should be done.